# Prove by induction on $n$ that for any $n \geq 1$ in a simple graph $G_n$ with $n$ vertices $|E(G_{n})|=1/2\sum_{v\in V(G_n)} \operatorname{deg}(v)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction

Here I found that for my base case of $n=1$, it is evident that there are no edges, therefore the cardinality of the edge set on the left is equal to $0$ and that the valency of my sole vertex on the right is also equal to $0$ as there are no edges.
For my inductive step, for an arbitrary $k\geq1$, then we get our induction hypothesis
$|E(G_{k})|=1/2\sum_{v\in V(G_k)} \operatorname{deg}(v)$. Here $V(G_k)$ is the vertex set and $E(G_k)$ is the edge set. Now from here I believe we are supposed to consider an arbitrary simple graph $G_{k+1}$ with $k+1$ vertices, remove one of the vertices from our arbitrary graph to give us our inductive hypothesis. We also know that the number of edges on the arbitrary graph is any number between $0$ and ${k+1 \choose 2}$. From here though, I am not quite sure where to go. I believe that once we remove this vertex, we then write down our IH, then add the vertex back to the graph. By adding this vertex back to the graph, what happens to each side of the equation and how are we getting our $k+1$ where we want it?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Search *handshake lemma*.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to do induction ok the number of edges. Suppose we have proved the result for a graph with $k$ edges and let G be a graph with $k+1$ edges.

If we delete an edge $e$ the graph satisfies $$|E - e| = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{v \in V} deg(v)$$. In the graph with $E$ both sides of the equation get summed by $1$, so it must be true for a graph with $k+1$ edges

Comment: yes, but in this case we are doing induction on the number of vertices

Comment: Oh sure. Consider that by adding the vertex back to the graph you are adding as many edges as its degree. Also, for every edge the degree of another node goes up by one. So after adding the node back the change in the sum of the degrees is twice the change in the number of edges.